# CEP Proton The key was not in the map, reason: The key was not in the map

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I was trying to integrate Proton with Orion, but when Orion is sending events to Proton, I always get the same error:

com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventJSONMessageReader readFrom
SEVERE: Could not parse json event org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONException: The key [Name] was not in the map, reason: The key [Name] was not in the map

I have reviewed the attributes names and they are OK.

See below the attrNames seen by Cygnus (already integrated with Orion)

```
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | Altitude | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | AltitudeDelta1 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | AltitudeDelta2 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | BatteryLevel | integer | 25 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | CO | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | COCal | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | CurrentRSSI | integer | -110 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | LastPacketRSSI | integer | -40 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | LastPacketSNR | integer | 8 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | Latitude | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | LatitudeDelta1 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | LatitudeDelta2 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | Longitude | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | LongitudeDelta1 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | LongitudeDelta2 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | NO | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | NO2 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | NO2Cal | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | NOCal | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | Ozone | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | OzoneCal | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | Serial | float | 25 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | Speed | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | SpeedDelta1 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | SpeedDelta2 | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | humidity | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | humidityCal | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | pressure | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | pressureCal | float | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | temperature | integer | 33 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | temperatureCal | float | 23 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | timestamp | integer | 140021212 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | timestampDelta | integer | 720 | [] |
| 1444683578 | 2015-10-12T20:59:38.352 | sensor4 | STCSensor | timestampDelta2 | integer | 23 | [] |
+------------+-------------------------+----------+------------+------------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

I also attach part of the project json exported.

```
{"epn":{"events":[{"name":"STCSensor","createdDate":"Mon Oct 12 2015","attributes":[
{"name":"entityType","type":"String","dimension":0},
{"name":"Serial","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"BatteryLevel","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"CurrentRSSI","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"LastPacketRSSI","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"LastPacketSNR","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"timestamp","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"timestampDelta","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"timestampDelta2","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"Latitude","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"Longitude","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"Altitude","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"Speed","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"LatitudeDelta1","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"LongitudeDelta1","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"AltitudeDelta1","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"SpeedDelta1","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"LatitudeDelta2","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"LongitudeDelta2","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"AltitudeDelta2","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"SpeedDelta2","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"temperature","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"pressure","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"humidity","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"temperatureCal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"pressureCal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"humidityCal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"CO","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"NO","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"NO2","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"Ozone","type":"Integer","dimension":0},
{"name":"COCal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"NOCal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"NO2Cal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"OzoneCal","type":"Double","dimension":0},
{"name":"entityId","type":"Integer","dimension":"0"}]},
```

Can you help me out please?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1):

The integration between CEP Proactive Technology Online (Proton) and Orion uses the xml format (not json).

The Post from Orion needs to include

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

The Appendix in the CEP Proactive Technology Online's [user guide](https://github.com/ishkin/Proton/tree/master/documentation) describes how to integrate between Orion and Proton.

Please note that the CEP event definition must have some attributes, and the name of the CEP input event must be [entity type]ContextUpdate, as described in the [user guide](https://github.com/ishkin/Proton/tree/master/documentation)'s appendix

Make sure to export your updated definition and stop & start the CEP to make it run with your updated definition

Comment: Thanks.Using xml I get this EVERE: Could not parse XML NGSI event java.lang.NullPointerException, reason: null
 last attribute name: null last value: null
Oct 13, 2015 8:11:35 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
INFO: finished event message body reader
Oct 13, 2015 8:11:35 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
INFO: starting submitNewEvent
Oct 13, 2015 8:11:35 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
SEVERE: Could not send event, reason: java.lang.NullPointerException, message: null

Comment: Please read the user guide appendix carefully. To see what need to be the name of the CEP input event and which attributes is must have in order to parse Orion message to input event. It seems that either the name of the event is incorrect or that one attribute is missing

Comment: I already did it but without success. I only left one attribute timestamp and, according to the user guide, I added entityType and entityId. So, there are only three atributes. :{"events":[{"name":"STCSensor","createdDate":"Mon Oct 12 2015","attributes":[{"name":"entityType","type":"String","dimension":0},{"name":"timestamp","type":"Integer","dimension":0},{"name":"entityId","type":"String","dimension":"0"}]}, Could you please tell me if the name of the event is incorrect or I miss anything?

Comment: The name of the event in the CEP should be: <entity type>ContextUpdate, if your entity type in Orion is STCSensor, then the name of the CEP event should be STCSensorContextUpdate

Comment: I also did it. {"name":"STCSensorContextUpdate","createdDate":"Tue Oct 13 2015","attributes":[{"name":"entityType","type":"String","dimension":0},{"name":"entityId","type":"String","dimension":0},{"name":"timestamp","type":"Integer","dimension":0}] But same result. Thanks

Comment: After you updated the CEP definition, did you export it, and then stop and start the CEP?

Comment: I tried but I'm getting error 500, error: unable to load /AuthoringToolWebServer/resources/proxy?url=myipaddress, ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/definitions status 500

Comment: This means that the CEP doesn't run with your updated definition. I would recommend to go over the installation guide and make sure you performed all the steps (especially setting the definition repository, and verify the write permissions). If you already managed to export+stop+start in the past, then you can try to restart tomcat

Comment: I have checked ProtonOnWebServerAdmin is running and repository is writable, but I'm still getting error 500. Using rest client I can access to resources/instances but not to definitions,is it required additional configuration?

Comment: Make sure all the configurations described under https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_Proactive_Technology_Online_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Configuring_the_administration_application are defined correctly

Comment: Followed all the guidelines but still not working. Could it be due to Docker container?

Comment: As a workaround, export your updated definition to a file, and change the ProtonOnWebServer/config/Proton.properties to point to this file. Then stop and start the CEP or restart tomcat

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error. I managed not using Proton docker, so I deployed it and this is the log I get in tomcat7 logs

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: A javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader implementation was not found for class org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONArray type and text/html;charset=utf-8 media type.  Verify that all entity providers are correctly registered.  Add a custom javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader provider to handle the type and media type if a JAX-RS entity provider does not currently exist.

Comment: Could you please provide more information - which Java, Tomcat versions, how did you deploy the CEP, according to the installation guide?

Comment: Please find more logs Oct 20, 2015 2:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ProtonAdminApplication] in context with path [/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin] threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
 at com.ibm.hrl.proton.admin.webapp.resources.DefinitionsResource.getAllDefinitions(DefinitionsResource.java:80)

Comment: java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I have run in the same issue with the Docker instance.
Despite the event definition respects the rules depicted in the Appendix A of the User Guide, the log continuously reports:

```
INFO: started event message body reader
Oct 26, 2015 1:25:36 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
SEVERE: Could not parse XML NGSI event java.lang.NullPointerException, reason: null
last attribute name: null last value: null
Oct 26, 2015 1:25:36 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
INFO: finished event message body reader
Oct 26, 2015 1:25:36 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
INFO: starting submitNewEvent
Oct 26, 2015 1:25:36 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
SEVERE: Could not send event, reason: java.lang.NullPointerException, message: null
```

I decied to try with the .war files in the artifacts folder (editing the Dockerfile), instead of the ones used in the Dockerfile (the original one). Now everything works, without change the event definition.

By comparing the logs file, I noticed that the following parts are missing in the catalina.out of the original Docker instance:

```
com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.executor.PropertiesParser loadProperties
INFO: Properties are : 
metadatFile =/tmp/defs/DoSAttack.json 
inputPortNumber =3002 
outputPortNumber =3302
```

Here the changes in the Dockerfile:

```
#WORKDIR /root/Proton/mvn-repo/com/ibm/hrl/proton/AuthoringTool/0.0.1
#RUN cp *war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/AuthoringTool.war
#WORKDIR /root/Proton/mvn-repo/com/ibm/hrl/proton/AuthoringToolWebServer/0.0.1
#RUN cp *war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/AuthoringToolWebServer.war
#WORKDIR /root/Proton/mvn-repo/com/ibm/hrl/proton/ProtonOnWebServer/0.0.1
#RUN cp *war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ProtonOnWebServer.war
#WORKDIR /root/Proton/mvn-repo/com/ibm/hrl/proton/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/0.0.1
#RUN cp *war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin.war
WORKDIR /root/Proton/artifacts
RUN cp AuthoringTool.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/AuthoringTool.war
RUN cp AuthoringToolWebServer.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/AuthoringToolWebServer.war 
RUN cp ProtonOnWebServer.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ProtonOnWebServer.war
RUN cp ProtonOnWebServerAdmin.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin.war
```